# Didn't understand the comments below about the possibility for a compiler to perform `memcpy` optimization for plain {} definitions

Tags: c++

I didn't quite understand the two comments below by @goodbyeera and @user743382 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22712452/2337207) in SO.

[Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711901/declaring-a-function-as-defaulted-after-its-first-declaration/22712452#comment34610838_22712452) by @goodbyeera:

> @hvd: In that sense, wouldn't the compiler perform `memcpy`
> optimization for plain `{}` definition too?

[Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711901/declaring-a-function-as-defaulted-after-its-first-declaration/22712452#comment34610937_22712452) by @user743382:

> @goodbyeera It's allowed, but it may be significantly harder for the
> compiler to detect that it's possible. A field-by-field assignment in
> the copy constructor function body may look to the compiler as if it
> should avoid copying any internal padding bytes.

Comment: I'm unable to discern what you are unable to quite understand from the comments.  If nothing else, the *as-if* rule definitely allows the compiler to use `memcpy`, but the compiler detecting that is an option may be more difficult.  You'd have to look as the assembly to be sure.  (I did not downvote.)

Comment: @Eljay Why would it be more difficult to detect that is an option? What do the padding bytes have to do with this?

Comment: More difficult to detect because the class will no longer be [`std::is_trivial`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial).  I do not know what the padding bytes have to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would it be more difficult to detect that is an option? What do the padding bytes have to do with this?

Imagine you have the following class definition:

```
class Foo
{
    char a;
    int b;

public:
    Foo (const Foo& other)
    {
        a = other.a;
        b = other.b;
    }
};
```

Now, if you had allowed the compiler to synthesize a default copy constructor, it would most likely implement it as an 8-byte `memcpy`, since it knows that the padding bytes between `a` and `b` (which are inserted for alignment purposes) are not important.  Said `memcpy` will be inlined and is probably 2 machine instructions.

However, with a user-defined copy constructor as shown, the compiler *might* think, "oh look, he's copying each member variable indivdually, I'd better respect that", and therefore generate sub-optimal code.  Whether it does or not, you could test on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) (I didn't, sorry).

Comment: Another example would be a class that contains an instance of another class, with user-defined default constructor and assignment operator, but the definition of those functions are not visible to the compiler (e.g. defined in a different compilation unit)   The compiler has no basis to assume that the copy construction of `Foo` has the same effect as a single `memcpy()` call.

Comment: @Peter Certainly, although I don't think that is what the OP was getting at.